# How do I run Protractor from a non-AngularCLI project?

Tags: angular, protractor

I just started using Protractor and I am ready run my first test. However, I have no idea how to do that. I have tried typing `ng e2e` in cmd, but apparently I "have to be inside an Angular CLI project in order to use the e2e command".

In the guide from http://www.protractortest.org/#/tutorial they tell you to run the test by creating a `conf.js` file and then typing `protractor conf.js` into cmd. I tried that, but when I enter the name of my spec file, like so:

```
specs: ['app.e2e-spec.ts']
```

I get an error:

```
[20:24:58] E/configParser - Error code: 105
[20:24:58] E/configParser - Error message: configuration file conf.js did not export a config object
```

I tried to change it to `.js` just to see what would happen, and then I didn't get any errors, but it said "No specs found". So, it seems like only `.js` files are accepted, but mine have the typescipt `.ts` ending. What is the correct way to do this? Thanks.

EDIT: Here's my directory structure:

[image]

Comment: Could you post your directory structure? Or at least tell us where  your `conf.js` and `app.e2e-spec.ts` files are located..thanks.

Comment: @alecxe Done. I deleted my `conf.js` file because I thought that wasn't the right way to do it. Should i recreate it?

Comment: so, with your structure now, i would be `protractor protractor.config.js`, assuming you specified your conf file to have `specs: [ 'e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts' ]`. make sure you are in the same dir as your config file when executing the above

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Typescript, the correct way as of now to call `spec.ts` files would be with the help of [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node) module.

Install `ts-node` module `npm install -S ts-node` to your project.

call your spec files in `config.ts` as follows:

```
specs: [
'./e2e/*-spec.ts'
],
beforeLaunch: function() {
require('ts-node').register({
  project: 'e2e'
});
},
```

**Note:** Once you compile your `config.ts`, you would have to eventually call `protractor config.js` only as it currently doesn't support calling config.ts directly.In future you might get this feature as well!

Since you have just started with protractor, I would advice to checkout the [Protractor-Cookbook](https://github.com/angular/protractor-cookbook). Here you would find all the configurations with examples!

Answer (score 0):

You should call a specific spec the below way:

```
protractor protractor-conf.js --specs=<path/specName1,path/specName2>
```

So, you have to have the protractor configuration as your first CLI arg. In your use case above, you need to have a file name `conf.js` in the directory that your run your protractor command from.